# Preventing ad image from being cached

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, caching, ads

I'm running Wordpress with Adrotate - note, this is not a Wordpress question - and an advertiser has send me images they want to run as ads. I know that if I put the images directly in the ads the impressions won't be tracked due to caching software (memcache) so I thought I'd circumvent that with some JavaScript. Would my method below work or do I need to do something like generate a random query string?

```
<script>
document.write("<div><a href=%link% target=_blank><img src=\"%image%\" height=\"250\" width=\"250\" /></a></div>");
</script>
```

Note: I don't know any JavaScript at all, so this will need to be spelled out explicitly for me! Also I played around with OpenX but it seems way too advanced for one simple ad campaign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a timestamp to image src param :

```
<script>
document.write("<div><a href=%link% target=_blank><img src=\"%image%?v=") ;
document.write(new Date().getTime());
document.write("\" height=\"250\" width=\"250\" /></a></div>");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That should do it!